# Big Query job in shell script

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to automate a Big Query job in shell script but I'm getting errors while trying to do this. I'm reading a local CSV file with two columns, reading line by line and updating the values, with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=","
while read f1 f2
do
        echo "De $f1 para $f2"
        bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "UPDATE agendas_usuarios.tb_usuarios SET cargo='${f2}' WHERE cargo='${f1}'"

done < cargos_ps.csv
```

But I'm getting a syntax error: Unclosed
string literal at [1:47].

I've seen something that Shell Script doesn't allow for single quotes inside double quotes, is that true? If so, what's the best way to do this job in shell? I really need to develop in another programming language?

My CSV reading is right, my echo before the bq query is showing correctly.

Comment: This applies to any scenario when you're debugging shell commands, but try using `echo` instead of `bq query` to see what the actual command will be.

Comment: Already did this, it strangely seems that the command is executing reverse, somehow. The output of echoing is this: ' WHERE cargo='[Nome do Cargo]'rios SET cargo='[Cargo correspondente]', this "rios" part is the tb_usuarios part, but somehow the command is overwriting itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the actual problem is (perhaps it's necessary to escape the quotes) but using [query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bigquery-query-params-cli) will mean that you don't need to inject strings into the query directly and can hopefully avoid the issue you're seeing. You'd want something like this:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \
  --parameter="cargo:STRING:${f2}" \
  --parameter="target:STRING:${f1}" \
  "UPDATE agendas_usuarios.tb_usuarios SET cargo=@cargo WHERE cargo=@target"
```

Comment: The job runs, but in a wrog way! Echoing this produces the following, somehow overwriting the own print and not showing the full message (note the "PLUPDATE", the 'target' parameter in this case is "INSP SINISTRO AUTO PL", but it "concats" with the UPDATE in a strange way: --parameter=target:STRING:INSP SINISTRO AUTO PLUPDATE agendas_usuarios.tb_usuarios SET cargo=@cargo WHERE cargo=@target

Comment: I see that's a problem with Big Query today, maybe this is causing this issue: https://status.cloud.google.com//incident/bigquery/19001?_ga=2.62457388.-1261490910.1510337855

Comment: That's unrelated